# Code to copy data starting at a specific value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

[graph of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdWzT.png)

I am trying to write a code that copies data from multiple csv files into a master sheet.

I have everything in the code correct but some of the data is offset by a thousand or so rows.
I need a code that goes into column B scans the values of the cells until it reaches the first cell with a value greater than 1; Or looking at the graph starting at the first big jump of data, and copies the data from the value greater than 1 until the end of the column.
I can't figure out a way to select the first cell in column B greater than 1

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1", ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Copy
```

This is the original code that I have but instead of a "B1" I want it to start at a certain cell value greater than 1

Comment: I think you'll have to loop from row 1 until you find a number >1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can avoid a loop. I'd prefer `End(xlup)` in case you have only one value in column B after the chosen cell or blanks in the middle.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long

Do
    r = r + 1
Loop Until Cells(r, 2).Value > 1

MsgBox "Row " & r

Range(Cells(r, "B"), Cells(r, "B").End(xlDown)).Copy
'ETC

End Sub
```